# React Native: how can I observe and send livedata in Android Native module

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I'm creating a native module in react native.
his role is to connect to something and listen to data from this thing.
But.. I don't know how to **observe** my liveData **property**.

I can't use **observeForever** because I cannot use it in the background thread. and can't use it with **reactContext looper**.
I can't use it either with **livedata.observe(owner)** because my **nativeModule** don't have lifeCycleOwner. And if I create mine, I got the following error: **Method handleLifeCycleEvent must be called on the main thread**

I tried everything I can and I didn't find any tutorial about what I want. Everyone use **sendEvent** when a and I didn't find any tutorial is called but never in background. the [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript) doesn't give enought information too...

here my module:

```kotlin
package com.my.module

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule



import com.someone.extsdk

class MyModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
  
  override fun getName() = "MyModule"  

  @ReactMethod fun connect(id: String, promise: Promise) {
    extsdk.connect(
      onSuccess = { promise.resolve(null) },
      onError =  { e -> promise.reject("connect", e.toString())}
    )
  }  

  @ReactMethod fun disconnect() {
    extsdk.disconnect()
  }  


  @ReactMethod fun addListener(eventName: String) {
    // How can I listen to extsdk.liveData?
  }
  
  @ReactMethod fun removeListeners(count: Int) {
    // How can I remove listener?
  }

  private fun sendEvent(reactContext: ReactContext, eventName: String, params: WritableMap?) {
    reactContext
      .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java)
      .emit(eventName, params)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time but I finally got it right.

Overview of how to do it:

- Call super constructor of ReactContextBaseJavaModule so it can give you the current Activity
- Initial View model only after the Activity is ready. For example, I initialized it from a method call from React Native side. I haven't explored any other way to initialize it until now.
- Create observer in a GlobeScope with Main dispatcher

Here is example code:

Call super

```
class MeditiveModule(private val context: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(context){
```

Initialize view model and create observer

```
@ReactMethod
fun testAPICall() {
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(currentActivity as AppCompatActivity,
    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(currentActivity!!.application)).get(MeditiveViewModel::class.java)
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        viewModel.signal.observe(currentActivity as AppCompatActivity, Observer {
            Log.d(tag, "LiveData: $it")
            // Call send event function here
        })
    }
}
```

In Java you can call

```
getCurrentActivity().getApplication()
```

in a ReactMethod to get Application object